# how to use perl regular expression to capture a particular text line

Tags: perl

I have the following text of lines

```
__Data__
test
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
-dkdkdkdkdkd

__Data__
test
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

I only want to capture the line of a's text. This code is not working. What's the regular expression to only capture a's line of text and put it into a my-type of variable

```
$/="__Data__";

open READFILE,"<", "one_test.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

while(<READFILE>) {
    if(/^test.*\n^([A-Za-z].*)\n(^.*)?/ms) {
        print $1,"\n";
        # my lineA = $1; not working, I can't use this variable outside the if construct (see below)
    }
    # print lineA; # does not work
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Also, in-line comments in Perl start with `#`, not `//`.

Comment: Comments in perl use the pound `#` symbol, not double slash `//`.

Comment: If the file isn't too big to fit in memory, I think slurping the thing into memory and a grep { /aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/ } split(/__Data__/) would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 3):

Besides your other errors, using the `/s` modifier will make wild card `.` match newline. Since you are using a greedy `.*`, it will match everything up to the end of the string, leaving nothing to be captured by your parens.

Solution is to either remove the `/s` modifier, or to make the match non-greedy by using `.*?` instead.

Your other errors:

- Comments start with `#` not `//`.
- `my lineA` -> `lineA` is a bareword, not a variable. Use `$lineA`.
- Using `my` within an enclosed block `{ my $var }` will limit its scope to that block. In order to use it outside the block, put the `my` declaration outside the block.
- `$/` is the ending of your records, so with your input having a leading `__DATA__`, you will first read in an empty record.
- Always use `use strict; use warnings;` because it will prevent simple mistakes and give you good debugging information. It saves a lot of time.
- Use proper indentation, and writing code will be much less of a hassle. I recommend using a proper editor that handles it for you, such as vim/gvim.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions from **TLP**. In your code, I don't know why you separate input with `__Data__`. I think there is more info I don't know, but one way could be reading the file line by line and the regexp would be as simple as this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $readfile ,"<", "one_test.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

my $lineA;

while ( <$readfile> ) { 
    chomp;
    $lineA = $1 if m/\A(a+)\Z/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a good reason why you want to read from `__Data__` to `__Data__`
TLP already explained why you need to drop the /s modifier.
Hence no more need to put '^' in the middle of your regex.
You need also a $ in front of your variable (guess that was a typo).
And you need to do the my declaration outside the if block, otherwise the variable is local to that block.

Here is sample code that (maybe) does what you were looking for:
(assuming there is only one line with 'a' to be found)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/="__Data__";
open READFILE,"<", "test.txt" or die "Unable to open file";
my $lineA;
while ( <READFILE> )  {
      if (/^test.*\n(a+)\n(.*)?/m) {
            $lineA = $1; 
      }
 }

 print "line with a's: $lineA\n";
```